# Can't install linux from the USB stick on fresh PC

Tags: linux, boot, usb, hardware-failure, bootable-media

Got a new fresh laptop `Acer Swift 3 (SF314-41)` without OS installed (in the boot manager I got only UEFI_SHELL).

Tried to install Ubuntu, but ended up with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315546/ubuntu-page-tab-hardware-error-boot-error/1315549?noredirect=1#comment2239580_1315549). Then, I have tried to install another linux distro - Manjaro with bootable USB stick and got `Security Boot Fail` error. Then I tried to launch Windows 10 installation (created bootable USB stick with their MediaCreationTool20H2) and found out that it loads successfully (I didn't try to install it)!

Both Ubuntu and Manjaro from the same stick can be booted successfully on another laptop `Fujitsu lifebook E 754`. Security boot is disabled, rufus settings: partition scheme GPT, target system: UEFI (non CSM).

Comment: Have you tried turning off PSB / Secure Boot from the BIOS?

Comment: @Darius, as mentioned in question - yes.

Comment: "UEFI (non CSM)" means that UEFI is activated without compatibility mode. https://superuser.com/a/1284407/309301

Comment: So what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Inserting "iommu=soft" into /boot/grub/grub.cfg in bootable USB helped me. Details [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1316042/1181399).